# __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

```
class Car():    
    def __init__(self, modelname, price, yearm):
        self.modelname=modelname
        self.price = price
        self.yearm = yearm

class supercar(Car):    
    def __init__(self, modelname, price, yearm, cc):
        super().__init__(self, modelname, price, yearm)
        self.cc = cc
    
honda=supercar('city', 100000, 2017, 1500)

print(honda.price)
```

Comment: Remove `self` from `super().__init__(self,modelname,price,yearm)`

Comment: `super().__init__` returns a bound method, as opposed to `Car.__init__` which would be an unbound method to which `self` has to be passed explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is used to represent the instance of the class. It binds the attributes with the given arguments.

When you pass self as an argument to base class's `init` method, it passes all the attributes of that object. Remove `self` when calling base class's `init` and call it like this-

```
super().__init__(modelname, price, yearm)
```